# Identifying and moving fields in a line

Tags: bash

I want to identify a field in a line containing a string, and then move it to a different position. A line would look like this (sorry, I can't seem to type tabs in here)

```
string1 / string2 / blablaABCbla / string3
```

The idea is to locate the field containing ABC and move this field to the beginning or end of the line. How would I do this in bash, from stdout?

[edit]

I'm trying to work this into a piped sequence - I was hoping for a clever command I didn't know about, or else something really sed-ugly.

Comment: Why it's not possible to use for example python, as that makes it way simpler?

Comment: @Olli - not everyone knows Python. The OP asked for the solution to be implemented using shell tools such as `bash`, `awk`, etc. You can write up an A if you feel Python would be the best option, but be sure to explain your rationale. If it's just b/c you know Python and not `awk` or `bash` then that's not a valid reason to write the solution up that way. On U&L those shell tools are the more typical way to solve most problems, but they are not the only ways.

Answer (score 2):

I use AWK (a standard UNIX/Linux command that there is even a Busybox implementation of) for a problem like that, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{srand()} {
    X=$0
    for(a=1;a<=NF;a++) {
        if($a ~ /ABC/) {
            if(rand() < .5) {
                X = $a " " $0 # Concat strings
            } else {
                X = $0 " " $a
            }
       }
   }
print X
}'
```

As an aside, I don't think the AWK solution is any more complicated than a Python one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
        fields = re.split('\t',line[:-1])
        out = line[:-1]
        for field in fields:
                if re.search('ABC',field):
                        if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
                                out = field + " " + line[:-1]
                        else:
                                out = line[:-1] + " " + field
        print out
```

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating a string in such a way as you've requested is a bit of work using just Bash. It's doable but I find using Perl to be much easier. This Perl one-liner will do what you want as well:

```
$ perl -a -F'\s*/\s*' -lne '
   printf "%s / ", grep( /ABC/, @F ); 
   printf "%s / %s / %s\n",  grep( !/ABC/, @F ); 
' file
blablaABCbla / string1 / string2 / string3
```

This solution assumes a 4 column formatted input, and that ABC will be present. You can reverse the order of the `printf...grep...` lines to get the ABC at the beginning (as shown) or at the end of the line. You'll need to make a couple of modifications like so:

```
$ perl -a -F'\s*/\s*' -lne '
   printf "%s / %s / %s / ",  grep( !/ABC/, @F ); 
   printf "%s\n", grep( /ABC/, @F );
' file 
string1 / string2 / string3 / blablaABCbla
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash oneliner could easily do the trick - tweak this **[string comparison oneliner from another stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613867/187885)** - to your purpose by:

> - adding “/“ to the field separator **IFS**
> - assigning a **fourth variable** to the read command to match each of your “fields”
> - test for your particular string “blabla…” and when that string is found
> - echo your 4 variables in **any preferred order** (or even assign the result to a new variable)
> - of course **instead of a text file as input**, you may want to use a **pipe** or a simple redirection as in: **<<<${myinput[@]}**