# Compare all Values from a column with a string

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have the next txt file:

```
      -----------------------------
       CPU(%)    SWAP     Memory(%)
      -----------------------------
      181.2     0kB       0.4
      12.5     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
      0.0     0kB       0.4
```

I would like to check that all the values in SWAP column are 0kB
hope someone can help me:)

Comment: Is your file really like that? Does it have all those spaces at the beginning of each line?

Comment: What do you want to happen if all the values are 0kB? A 1 exit code? A friendly message? A whistle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `awk`. Just print any line where the first fields consists entirely of numbers or `.` (so we can skip the header lines) and the second field is not `0kB`:

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9.]*$/ && $2!="0kB"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me old-fashioned and surely not performance focused, but for some reason I always revert to **bash loops** in such situations, I feel more *"in control"* this way. **[ndlr: this is bash only]**

```
> $ cat mytxt.txt

     -----------------------------
      CPU(%)    SWAP     Memory(%)
     -----------------------------
     181.2      0kB       0.4
      12.5      1kB       0.4
       0.0     10kB       0.4
       0.0      0kB       0.4
       0.0      0kB       0.4
       0.0      0kB       0.4
       0.0      0kB       0.4
       0.0      0kB       0.4
```

Navigate in your terminal to the folder of your above text file, paste the one liner below (change *“mytxt.txt”* to match your file name)

```
_x=0 ; while IFS=" " read -r _mycpu _myswap _mymem; do ((_x++)) ; case "${_mycpu//\ /}" in [0-9]*) if [[ ! "${_myswap//\ /}" =~ ^"0kB" ]]; then echo -e "line $_x) \t${_mycpu} \t${_myswap} \t${_mymem}"; else : ; fi ;; *|"")   : ;; esac ; done < mytxt.txt
```

Press return et... Voilà!

```
line 5)     12.5    1kB     0.4
line 6)     0.0     10kB    0.4
```

The same oneliner code in a more friendly format and with explanations:

```
_x=0 ; \
while IFS=" " read -r _mycpu _myswap _mymem; do \
  ((_x++)) ; \
  case "${_mycpu//\ /}" in \
     [0-9]*) if [[ ! "${_myswap//\ /}" =~ ^"0kB" ]]; then \
               echo -e "line $_x) \t${_mycpu} \t${_myswap} \t${_mymem}"; \
              else : ; fi ;; \
     *|"")   : ;; \
  esac ; \
done < mytxt.txt
```

> **explanations**
>
> - _x= line counter incremented by 1 (_x++) when reading each line
> - IFS=" “ : set the separator to "spaces" when reading each line from the file, this allows to attribute each space separated block of text
>   to 3 variables, _mycpu, _myswap and _mymem
> - we then test that the first variable of each line *_mycpu* starts with a number, first we strip any pesky white space from the variable,
>   just in case, by using the “remove” bash string manipulation: “//“ to
>   select “\ “ to indicate a SPACE and “/“ to indicate the replacement
>   string (in our case: NOTHING): *${_mycpu//\ /}* then we test it for a
>   number with: *case [0-9]*) ... ;; statement* - this avoid processing
>   tests on the blank lines, title and line separators - other conditions
>   can easily be added.
> - the case *|"") : ;; statement is for clarity sake: in all other cases simply continue executing the rest of the code.
> - in the first case we then test _myswap against the value “0kB", the condition is using the "approx" comparison "=~" negated by the ! at
>   the start of the if statement: [[ ! ... =~ ]] ; we test for the
>   variable to start with "0kB" by adding the ^ [[ ... =~ ^"0kB" ]].
>   Hence if _myswap does not start with "0kB" then we echo the line
>   number _x and the value of each of the other variables
> - we close the while ... read... do... loop with the done statement
> - last **we feed the entire loop** with the text file using the < redirector.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "s/^\s+/ /g" filename| awk 'BEGIN{print "-----------------------------------------------------\n  CPU(%)    SWAP     Memory(%)\n -------------------------------------------- "} {gsub("kB","",$0)}{if($2 == "0"){print $0}}'
```

output

```
-----------------------------------------------------
  CPU(%)    SWAP     Memory(%)
 -------------------------------------------- 
 181.2     0       0.4
 12.5     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
 0.0     0       0.4
```